# How to specify GNU screen ACL as part of its command line?

Tags: access-control-list, gnu-screen, gnu

What I'm trying to do is spawn a detached screen session, but as part of the command line that creates it - also modify the ACL list.

So right now I have

```
screen -dmS MySession "SomeProgram" "SomeArguments"
```

If I want to modify the ACL of MySession to give another user access to it, I'd have to run a second screen command to run a 'screen' command on that session.

What I need to do is modify the ACL as part of the initial command line used to spawn the session. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the ACLs in a seperate `screenrc` and load that with `-c`:

e.g.: `/opt/multi-screen-rc`

```
multiuser on
acladd user1
acladd user2
```

Then run like this:

```
screen -c /opt/multi-screen-rc -dmS MySession /usr/bin/foo bar baz
```